# jQuery If else show and hide for individual dropdown

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Would like to ask how should I make it one by one to open a dropdown. Currently, when I make a click event, all of them will open. Also how can I hide it back if it was not use?

Here's my code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
if ($(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu').show();
        else {
        $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dogs</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>    
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>        
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dogs Beds & Bedding</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>    
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>        
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dogs Coats & Clothes</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>    
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>        
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

How can I make them open individually if I just click one of them.

Comment: Add this => `H T M L`

Comment: @Pedram i've added my html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if ($(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {` totally is wrong and you don't need `if` and `else` here, just use `click` function then use `$(this)` and `next()` to find target `ul` then use `fadeToggle()` or `slideToggle()` to show/hide *(or `toggleClass()`)*.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.dropdown-menu').not($(this).next('.dropdown-menu')).fadeOut()
    $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').fadeToggle().toggleClass('isOpen');
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dogs</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dogs Beds & Bedding</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dogs Coats & Clothes</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Pedram - the code is working but it was not smooth coz it goes to the header when clicked.

Comment: *not smooth coz it goes to top when clicked* | I don't understand your mean. please explain more. @KobeBryan

Comment: Pedram - one last question. How can I close the opened dropdown if I want to click another dropdown?

Comment: Pedram -- quick question. how can I close the dropdown if I want to click from everywhere and it will automatically close?

Comment: @KobeBryan Yeah, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it) topic

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu").hide();
  $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu").hide();
    $(this).next(".dropdown-menu").show();
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu").hide();
  $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu").hide();
    $(this).next(".dropdown-menu").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dogs</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dogs Beds & Bedding</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dogs Coats & Clothes</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Carsten - how can I bring back the hide if the dropdown is unused?

Answer (score 1):

For better practice you should use `.toggle()`. Which allready checks if an element is *visible*.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   
    // Hide all dropdowns by default
    $(".dropdown-menu").hide();        

    $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {

        // .next() selects next sibling. In this case <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dogs</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>    
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>        
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dogs Beds & Bedding</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>    
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>        
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dogs Coats & Clothes</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>    
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>        
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Comment: Red -- the code is working but it was not smooth when drop down. How can I make it smoother?

Comment: Also, how can I close the dropdown when I wanted to open another one?

Comment: Using `slideToggle()`